sigaction handler is waiting for lock indefinitely
I recently written a signal handler which uses backtrace from execinfo.h and it is working fine on MacOs but when it is used on Linux (Ubuntu Debian) it is waiting for lock indefinitely. I'm not sure if this helps, but my multi-threaded program (pthread) uses rocksdb to store data and I intentionally kept a segfault in rocksdb so that I can test my signal handler if any issue occurs at rocksdb end but I am not able debug why lock is waiting.
This is the stacktrace I got on gdb:
#0  futex_wait (private=0, expected=2, futex_word=0x77e088a1ac80 <main_arena>) at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:146
#1  __GI___lll_lock_wait_private (futex=futex@entry=0x77e088a1ac80 <main_arena>) at ./nptl/lowlevellock.c:34
#2  0x000077e0888a53c8 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=408) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3327
#3  0x000077e088c024a3 in malloc (size=408) at ../include/rtld-malloc.h:56
#4  _dl_scope_free (old=old@entry=0x5660325219f0) at ./elf/dl-scope.c:34
#5  0x000077e088bf3308 in _dl_map_object_deps (map=map@entry=0x566032520dc0, preloads=preloads@entry=0x0, npreloads=npreloads@entry=0, 
    trace_mode=trace_mode@entry=0, open_mode=open_mode@entry=-2147483648) at ./elf/dl-deps.c:635
#6  0x000077e088bfda0f in dl_open_worker_begin (a=a@entry=0x7fff4a7a5010) at ./elf/dl-open.c:592
#7  0x000077e088974a98 in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fff4a7a4e70, operate=operate@entry=0x77e088bfd900 <dl_open_worker_begin>, 
    args=args@entry=0x7fff4a7a5010) at ./elf/dl-error-skeleton.c:208
#8  0x000077e088bfcf9a in dl_open_worker (a=a@entry=0x7fff4a7a5010) at ./elf/dl-open.c:782
#9  0x000077e088974a98 in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fff4a7a4ff0, operate=operate@entry=0x77e088bfcf60 <dl_open_worker>, 
    args=args@entry=0x7fff4a7a5010) at ./elf/dl-error-skeleton.c:208
#10 0x000077e088bfd34e in _dl_open (file=<optimized out>, mode=-2147483646, caller_dlopen=0x77e088925611 <__GI___libc_unwind_link_get+81>, nsid=-2, argc=3, 
    argv=<optimized out>, env=0x5660324f9fe0) at ./elf/dl-open.c:883
#11 0x000077e088974e01 in do_dlopen (ptr=ptr@entry=0x7fff4a7a5240) at ./elf/dl-libc.c:95
#12 0x000077e088974a98 in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7fff4a7a51e0, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>)
    at ./elf/dl-error-skeleton.c:208
#13 0x000077e088974b63 in __GI__dl_catch_error (objname=0x7fff4a7a5230, errstring=0x7fff4a7a5238, mallocedp=0x7fff4a7a522f, operate=<optimized out>, 
    args=<optimized out>) at ./elf/dl-error-skeleton.c:227
#14 0x000077e088974f37 in dlerror_run (args=0x7fff4a7a5240, operate=0x77e088974dc0 <do_dlopen>) at ./elf/dl-libc.c:45
#15 __libc_dlopen_mode (name=name@entry=0x77e0889db527 "libgcc_s.so.1", mode=mode@entry=-2147483646) at ./elf/dl-libc.c:162
#16 0x000077e088925611 in __GI___libc_unwind_link_get () at ./misc/unwind-link.c:50
#17 __GI___libc_unwind_link_get () at ./misc/unwind-link.c:40
#18 0x000077e088933b77 in __GI___backtrace (array=array@entry=0x77e088af0000 <backtrace_frames>, size=size@entry=1) at ./debug/backtrace.c:69
#19 0x000077e088a65f92 in dumpBackTrace () at my_faultHandler.c:366
#20 0x000077e088a66027 in faultHandler (signo=6) at my_faultHandler.c:344
#21 <signal handler called>
#22 __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=131806249563968) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#23 __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=131806249563968) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#24 __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=131806249563968, signo=signo@entry=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#25 0x000077e088842476 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#26 0x000077e0888287f3 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#27 0x000077e088889676 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x77e0889dbb77 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#28 0x000077e0888a0cfc in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x77e0889de5b8 "malloc_consolidate(): unaligned fastbin chunk detected") at ./malloc/malloc.c:5664
#29 0x000077e0888a198c in malloc_consolidate (av=av@entry=0x77e088a1ac80 <main_arena>) at ./malloc/malloc.c:4750
#30 0x000077e0888a3bdb in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x77e088a1ac80 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=32816) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3965
#31 0x000077e0888a5139 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=bytes@entry=32816) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3329
#32 0x000077e0888e630b in __alloc_dir (statp=0x7fff4a7a5ec0, flags=0, close_fd=true, fd=39) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/opendir.c:115
#33 opendir_tail (fd=39) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/opendir.c:63
#34 __opendir (name=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/opendir.c:86
#35 0x000077e087f93748 in rocksdb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::GetChildren (this=<optimized out>, 
    dir="/home/dummy/rocks", result=0x7fff4a7a6080)
    at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:2309
#36 0x000077e087eeaae0 in rocksdb::DBImpl::FindObsoleteFiles (this=this@entry=0x56603283fc40, job_context=job_context@entry=0x7fff4a7a6180, force=force@entry=true, 
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
    no_full_scan=no_full_scan@entry=false) at db/db_impl_files.cc:200
#37 0x000077e087eccfd3 in rocksdb::DBImpl::~DBImpl (this=0x56603283fc40, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at db/db_impl.cc:308
#38 0x000077e087ecd3f6 in rocksdb::DBImpl::~DBImpl (this=0x56603283fc40, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at db/db_impl.cc:357
#39 0x000077e087e66e9d in rocksdb_close (db=0x5660328a2b20) at db/c.cc:627

Signal handler code:
void RegisterFaultHandler(void)
{
    struct sigaction bt_action;

    sigemptyset(&bt_action.sa_mask);
    bt_action.sa_handler = &faultHandler;
    bt_action.sa_flags   = SA_RESTART | SA_ONSTACK;

    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &bt_action, prev_action + SIGSEGV) || sigaction(SIGBUS, &bt_action, prev_action + SIGBUS) ||
        sigaction(SIGILL, &bt_action, prev_action + SIGILL) || sigaction(SIGABRT, &bt_action, prev_action + SIGABRT) ||
        sigaction(SIGFPE, &bt_action, prev_action + SIGFPE) || sigaction(SIGSYS, &bt_action, prev_action + SIGSYS))
    {
        int savedErrno = errno;
        exit(1);
    }
}

static void unRegisterFaultHandler()
{
    /* Install 'previous' fault handler for all 'crash' (fatal) signals */
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, prev_action + SIGSEGV, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGBUS, prev_action + SIGBUS, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGILL, prev_action + SIGILL, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGABRT, prev_action + SIGABRT, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGFPE, prev_action + SIGFPE, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGSYS, prev_action + SIGSYS, NULL);
}

static void faultHandler(int signo)
{
    /* Disable fault_handler to call previous fault handlers, if any */
    unRegisterFaultHandler();

    dumpBackTrace();

    /* Propagate the signal back to, previous handler */
    raise(signo);
}

static void dumpBackTrace()
{
    int bt_fd = openBackTraceFile(); /* This will just open my file with open() system call */

    if (bt_fd >= 0)
    {
        static void *backtrace_frames[10];
        int          size = backtrace(backtrace_frames, 10);

        backtrace_symbols_fd(backtrace_frames, size, bt_fd);

        close(bt_fd);
    }
    else
    {
        const char error[] = "Cannot open backtrace file\n";

        (void)write(STDERR_FILENO, error, sizeof(error));
    }
}

I understand that calling malloc in frame #3 might be the reason as it is unsafe but I don't know how to fix this. Tried searching the internet for answers I was only able to get to the malloc part. Please let me know if you need any more info.
EDIT-1:
I am only getting this issue when segmentation fault occurs at rocksdb end and I am not getting any in my program. I think it might be due to error occuring because of malloc_consolidate and backtrace itself is again calling malloc

Rockdb is using c++ and my program and backtrace is using c so tagged both. If needed will remove it. Thanks for the heads up @RichardCritten

There are very few things you're allowed to do in a signal handler. Details e.g. here.

Backtrace inside Signal Handler

Your signal handler is fundamentally broken - it is not async-signal-safe.
Per C11 7.1.4 Use of library functions, paragraph 4:

The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify objects with static or thread storage duration.188

Note the link to footnote 188:


Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions.


Per POSIX 7 "Signal Concepts and the Linux signal-safety man page, there is a limited set of "async-signal-safe" functions that may be called from within a signal handler.
Functions not on those lists can not be safely called from within a signal handler.
Of particular interest in your backtrace is this line:

#3  0x000077e088c024a3 in malloc (size=408) at ../include/rtld-malloc.h:56

malloc() is not on any list of async-signal-safe functions, and calling malloc() from within a signal handler - even indirectly - is not safe and can cause problems, such as deadlocks.
Per the backtrace() documentation, backtrace() is async-signal-unsafe for multiple reasons:

Function: int backtrace (void **buffer, int size)
Preliminary: | MT-Safe | AS-Unsafe init heap dlopen plugin lock | AC-Unsafe init mem lock fd | See POSIX Safety Concepts

libunwind provides async-signal-safe functionality, and is available as part of most Linux distros.

Understood the problem. Can you suggest some solution to it.

If you just want to see a stack trace, the easiest way is to make sure your ulimit allows a core file to be dumped, and then just look at the stack trace in that. SEGV etc. are practically unrecoverable anyway.

core dump is fine but it will consume lot of memory, right? so a simple stacktrace would be better to know debug.

All that "memory" was already in memory. It's just getting paged to disk as well...

@widesense libunwind has async-signal-safe stack trace functinality.  It's typically part of most Linux distros.

Okay, will check it out. Thank you

Also seen the rocksdb signal handler code. Seems like they are partly taking care of this stuff. https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/port/stack_trace.cc

@widesense That might be the worst signal handler I've ever seen.  fprintf()?  popen()?  backtrace() itself - again? Even fork() is no longer required to be async-signal-safe because glibc broke it and they've spent more than a decade wearing down the POSIX committee because it's too hard for them to fix glibc to make their fork() implementation async-signal-safe (something that's not "too hard" for anyone else...)

Seems like I have lot to learn. Good to know this.

As already answered, the problem is that you can only call async-signal-safe library functions from inside a signal handler.
General Solution
The simplest way to call async-signal-unsafe functions in response to a signal is just to respond outside of a signal handler.
Usually you can block delivery of the interesting signals in all threads using sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ...), except for a dedicated thread which can wait in sigwaitinfo() for signals to handle in a non-async context.
SEGV Solution
Unfortunately that doesn't work for anyway for SIGSEGV, as that's delivered synchronously to the offending thread.
So, you have a regular signal handler, but it needs an async-signal-safe way of communicating to some other (non-async) context, and then potentially to sleep until that other context is done.
This is totally feasible, except that the call to backtrace() will now happen in a different thread whose call stack you don't care about.
Just Dump Core
Since several of your signals are anyway unrecoverable and will dump a core - containing a stack trace - by default, just leaving them alone and making sure ulimit permits a core file is the simplest solution.
C++23 std::basic_stacktrace
If you can use C++23 and a compiler that supports it, and provide an async-signal-safe allocator for it to use, then this may work.
If you can't use C++23 or your compiler doesn't support it yet, you can still use Boost.Stacktrace which came before.
However, consider this note on the subject in the Boost library - essentially listing some reasons async-signal-safety is problematic, and saying you have to inspect the source yourself to have any certainty.

Also https://github.com/libunwind/libunwind

I knew there was something else I was forgetting, thanks!

Even https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace is mentioned to be async signal safe. @Useless
